# List<WebElement> for only first 3 columns of the table

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit

Where it says `findElements(By.xpath("td[]"))`, how to get only the `td[1]`, `td[2]`, `td[3]` elements in the `List`?

```
WebElement Webtable = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
List<WebElement> TotalRowCount = Webtable.findElements(By.xpath(""));
int RowIndex = 1;
for (WebElement rowElement : TotalRowCount) {
    List<WebElement> TotalColumnCount = rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td[]"));
    int ColumnIndex = 1;
    for (WebElement colElement : TotalColumnCount) {
        ColumnIndex = ColumnIndex +1;
    }
    RowIndex = RowIndex + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using [`position()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position) function of the `xpath` as below which would select only first three columns for each row :-

```
List<WebElement> TotalColumnCount = rowElement.findElements(By.xpath("td[position() <= 3]"));
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what i was looking for! Also, i found that position()<4 works for the first three columns. I don't know why. When i user 3, it only checks the first two columns.

Comment: Position() < 3 does not include when position is equal to 3.. You could use position() <= 3 for readability

Comment: `position()` starts at index = 1, not index = 0 as you might think. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/position

Answer (score 0):

Just add those items to your list.

```
WebElement Webtable = driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));
int num_elements_to_get = 3;
int rows = Webtable.findElements(By.xpath("tr")).size();
List<WebElement> data = new ArrayList<WebElement>();
for(int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
    for(int j = 1; j <= num_elements_to_get; j++) {
        data.add(Webtable.findElement(By.xpath("tr["+i+"]/td["+j+"]")));
    }
}
```

Then the column elements that you want will be stored in data.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the quick reply! So, i need those elements for the specific rowElement i.e, i want td[1],td[2],td[3] for the specific rowElement. Its a nested for-loop and i'm confused how to implement your solution..

Comment: So you want the first 3 elements of each row? Ill edit my answer

Comment: Yes, first 3 elements of each row.

Comment: It makes sense but it was a little complicated to work it into my code; the solution below seems less complicated.